# Как правильно создать логику скрипта "сделка без риска"?

Tags: php, mysql

Создаю механизм перевода денег между аккаунтами с **безопасной сделкой**.

Необходимо перевести деньги с X аккаунта на Y и заморозить их в Y аккаунте на заданное время, например на 3 дня.

Так же необходимо иметь возможность с X аккаунта разморозить деньги на Y аккаунте в срок менее 3 дней, нажал на кнопку и деньги разморозились.

Еще нужно уметь заблокировать перевод, но без возврата денег, дать эту функцию администратору, чтобы он принял решение - арбитраж.

Сейчас у меня готов механизм простого перевода денег между аккаунтами, как организовать сделку без риска?

Логику понять не могу :(

Видимо при переводе денег, дополнительно нужно передать какие-то параметры, статусы в базу данных?

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Спасибо!

Comment: Самая простейшая логика в безопасной сделке - это то, что отправитель убедился в получателе, и готов сделать перевод. В этом случае требуется получить согласие обоих сторон, а уже после этого делать перевод. Но как вам уже сказали, там есть намного больше слоев чем это концептуальное объяснение, так как включает и возврат, и много еще чего.

Answer (score 1):

Иван!
На белом свете существует много service, предлагающих резервирование средств по вашему сценарию. Один такой есть "из русских" - https://www.safecrow.ru/.
Есть API, и это платно (%).

На своей стороне пилить такой велосипед напильником я бы не стал: роль арбитра в споре - уже большая ответственность, а резервирование средств должно предусматривать множество факторов, таких как безопасность хранения, страхование, лицензия и т. д.

Если вас интересует логика хранения информации о сделках, то тут всё просто: пишете в базу таблы с датами, флагами, именами (все необходимые поля, некоторые с ключами).

Удачи в бизнесе!